# Docker & WSL Ubuntu on Windows cannot find docker-entrypoint.sh - file not found

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After successfully setting up Docker and WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) on Windows, I can successfully run Docker and build images from within WSL. I followed the excellent article from Nick Janetakis [here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly)

However when I run a container I get this error:

Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh\": stat /bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown

The containers Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM ruby:2.4-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add build-base postgresql postgresql-dev git less make

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN bundle install

# Clean up
RUN apk del build-base

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 2999
EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

So it cannot find the entrypoint file even though it is there inside /bin in the WSL.

As far as I can tell this is not a windows/unix CR/LF issue as reported in other blogs/questions.

So how can I make this dockerfile 'see' the entrypoint file that is in WSL (ie. it is there in the container in WSL)?

**NOTE**

If I change the last line to ENTRYPOINT ["echo","Hello"] then it runs, but obviously does not call the entrypoint script. I am trying to understand why it cannot find that script, since it IS there.

Comment: did you try the absolute path like "/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"?

Comment: Yes I did, no luck, same error.

Comment: And does your container work if you use just regular version of base image like `FROM ruby:2.4` rather than alpine version?

Comment: No the container won't work from the base image because line 3 is RUN apk, and that is not in the base image.

Comment: Have you tried to exec inside the container to validate if script is where it is supposed to be and if it is executable? Try `docker run -it image_name sh`

Comment: When I try that, it puts me into the bash shell. Then I can type bin/docker-entrypoint.sh and it calls the script. So it is definitely there. This is so weird!

Comment: Indeed this is weird. If possible try building and running your image outside WSL.

Comment: It builds and runs fine in Linux and Mac. It builds in WSL, it even runs if I remove the ENTRYPOINT statement from the Dockerfile. So why it cannot find that file is a mystery.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I am having the same issue

Comment: @ShehanSimen Yes, which is the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that docker-compose mount drive was no longer accessible.

This is because I had reset my Windows password earlier this week which caused the Docker Desktop/Windows Shared Drive to be lost.

Since we are using docker-compose to mount a volume for the app, it could no longer see it as the shared drive was no longer switched on in Docker Dekstop.

This:
https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1854#issuecomment-387778063

From the docker-compose file:
api:
    build: .
    command: puma -C config/puma.rb
    volumes:
      - .:/app

From docker-compose perspective that volume is basically empty, hence the file not found error.

Answer (score 1):

That's how you `Dockerfile` should look like:

```
FROM ruby:2.4-alpine                                                                                                                                                                          

RUN apk update && apk add build-base postgresql postgresql-dev git less make                                                                                                                  

RUN mkdir /app                                                                                                                                                                                
WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                  
COPY Gemfile .                                                                                                                                                                  
COPY Gemfile.lock .

RUN bundle install                                                                                                                                                                            

# Clean up                                                                                                                                                                                    
RUN apk del build-base                                                                                                                                                                        

COPY . /app/                                                                                                                                                                                  

EXPOSE 2999                                                                                                                                                                                   
EXPOSE 3000                                                                                                                                                                                   

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

The point is in the last line. You have to use the absolute path like `/app/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`

**Updated**

Here is an example of docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/ash

exec "${@}"
```

and here is the "whole" files structure:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── docker-entrypoint.sh
├── Dockerfile
├── Gemfile
└── Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and a full answer with explanation, but if I do that won't it then break the Dockerfile for other devs working on Mac or Linux?

Comment: I guess it won't break. As I understand you can run building docker image from that file on any system and it will work. I've checked it on Linux for example

Comment: But anyway it throws the same error, file not found. :(

Comment: Yes, still not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192420/discussion-between-user3309314-and-rmcsharry).